# How can I prevent HTML encoding on a FormView?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-4.0

I am trying to display a property (land) size in the *ItemTemplate* of a FormView control, and the size value is a string that is sometimes square metres and sometimes hectares, so I can't hardcode a `<sup>` tag suffix, but I need to display the unit as `m<sup>2</sup>` when appropriate. How do I prevent the tags being encoded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use javascript to add/remove the formatting tags when the form-submit event fires.